# Editing tooltip text in chart using Google Earth Engine JavaScript API

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am creating a chart in Google Earth Engine showing a vegetation index for a number of different regions. I want to edit the tooltip text so the name of the region is shown, followed by the year, with "VCI:" and then the bold value on the second line rather than the really long number.

How can I edit this tooltip?

```
var chart_all =
    ui.Chart.image
        .seriesByRegion({
          imageCollection: lt_vci,
          regions: AOI,
          reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
          scale: 500,
          xProperty: 'year'
        })
        .setSeriesNames(['VCI'])
        .setOptions({
          title: 'Average Vegetation Condition Index by region ('+ m + '), ' + region,
          hAxis: {title: 'Date', titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}},
          vAxis: {
            title: 'VCI',
            titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}
          },
          lineWidth: 1,
          colors: ['e37d05', '1d6b99'],
          curveType: 'function'
        });
print(chart_all);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can define the series names. at the moment you have this:

```
.setSeriesNames(['VCI'])
```

But try if this works:

```
.setSeriesNames(['series1', 'series2', 'series3'])
```

Depending on the amount of variables of course.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. Also ideally I would like the code to automatically take the region name from the AOI feature class rather than having to put in the names each time. I tried creating a variable to do this and inputting that in the setSeriesNames function but also had no luck

Comment: Then you should adjust your question and provide an example that actually aims for that.. Hard to reproduce this, but you could consider building a list that contains the names from your AOI feature class

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use seriesProperty in ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion. I set this to the field containing the region names (ADM2_EN) in the feature collection. This code works correctly:

```
var chart_all =
    ui.Chart.image
        .seriesByRegion({
          imageCollection: lt_vci,
          regions: AOI,
          reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
          scale: 500,
          xProperty: 'year',
          seriesProperty: 'ADM2_EN' 
        })
        .setSeriesNames(['VCI'])
        .setOptions({
          title: 'Average Vegetation Condition Index by region ('+ m + '), ' + region,
          hAxis: {title: 'Date', titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}},
          vAxis: {
            title: 'VCI',
            titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}
          },
          lineWidth: 1,
//          colors: ['e37d05', '1d6b99'],
          curveType: 'function'
        });
print(chart_all);
```